# Objective C assignment calling setter?

Tags: objective-c

I have a field:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, nullable) BOOL questionCreated;
@property(nonatomic, nullable) NSString question;
```

If I create a setter for question like:

```
-(void)setQuestion:(NSString)question {
  _question = question;
  _questionCreated = YES;
}
```

And then in another file suppose I have an instance of `SomeClass` called `someClassInstance`.

If I do something like:

```
someClassInstance.question = "manually set question"
```

to my surprise I see that `someClassInstance.questionCreated` now also has the value `YES`, which makes me believe it calls the setter directly if I do `someClassInstance.question`. Why is this and how I can forcefully only set one of the field?

Comment: You want `NSString *` not `NSString`.

Comment: @trojanfoe, small detail, but what about the main issue?

Comment: The reason `questionCreated` is set to `YES` is because you set it to yes in your `setQuestion:` method.  However I don't see how it even compiles, so...

Comment: Yeah, but if I so `someClassInstance.question = "manual"`, I am asking why it calls the setter instead of just setting the field explicitly? Is that not possible?

Comment: Ah, that's Objective-C syntactic sugar, of which there is enough to rot your teeth.  It's equivalent to `[someClassInstance setQuestion:@"question"];`

Answer (score 2):

This line of code:

```
someClassInstance.question = @"manually set question";
```

is the same as this line of code:

```
[someClassInstance setQuestion:@"manually set question"];
```

And by "the same," I mean the former is converted into the latter at compile time. This is what "dot notation" means in Objective-C.

(Side note: when this syntax was added to ObjC in 2007 it was pretty controversial, specifically because it causes the kinds of confusion that you've run into. I was not a fan at the time. Like most folks, however, I've grown very accustomed to the sugar and it is easier to type, so you get used to it. But your confusion is not surprising.)

As a rule, external objects should not be concerned about the internal details of the setter. If they are, something is incorrectly designed (I would probably rename `setQuestion` to something else).

But another approach is to provide a direct setter. This is most often prefixed "primitive" like:

```
- (void)setPrimitiveQuestion:(NSString *)question {
    _question = question;
}
```

And then you build `setQuestion` on top of that:

```
- (void)setQuestion:(NSString *)question {
    [self setPrimitiveQuestion: question];
    self.questionCreated = @YES;
}
```

To your actual question, yes it is possible to do exactly what you're suggesting. It is generally bad form, but if you really need it you can reach in and modify ivars directly:

```
someClassInstance->_question = @"...";
```

But don't do this unless you really know what you're doing.